# Loop through textboxes with datetime

Tags: vb.net

I have this code to add days to the first day of the month.Could someone help me to write this shorter by looping through the Textboxes and add to each box an extra day?

```
Dim dpt As DateTimePicker = DateTimePicker1
Dim day1 As DateTime = dpt.Value.ToString("01/MM/yyyy")
Dim textBoxes() As TextBox = {TextBox187, TextBox188, TextBox189, TextBox190, TextBox191,TextBox192, TextBox193, TextBox194, TextBox195, TextBox196, TextBox197, TextBox198, TextBox199, TextBox200, TextBox201, TextBox202, TextBox203, TextBox204, TextBox205, TextBox206, TextBox207, TextBox208, TextBox209, TextBox210, TextBox211, TextBox212, TextBox213, TextBox214, TextBox215, TextBox216, TextBox217}

textBoxes(0).Text = day1
textBoxes(1).Text = day1.AddDays(1)
textBoxes(2).Text = day1.AddDays(2)
textBoxes(3).Text = day1.AddDays(3) etc..
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using a simple `for` loop? You surely can at least make an attempt...

Comment: @Adyson..Yes now that I see the code I could try harder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`For` loop should fit here:

```
For i = 0 To textBoxes.Length - 1
  textBoxes(i).Text = day1.AddDays(i)
Next
```

Comment: `day1.AddDays(i).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`?

Comment: @ Michal Turczyn..Thanks alot